# IIS7 How-To : Basic Folder Authentication

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7, http-basic-authentication

i am really lost with this problem and im hoping someone can help me out with some good old fashioned instructions.

i was able in windows 2003 to setup a folder on our webserver so when navigating to it, the brower would request a username and password which you entered, if this was not done the site would give an Not Authorized message etc etc.

I am close to pulling me hair out with IIS7 as i cannot find a way to-do this anymore, it seems to use the browser to authenticate against my PC login details...

can someone please point me in the direction of some plain old fashioned instructions on how i accomplish this task??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS 7 is a lot more modular than IIS 6: when you install it (by adding the "web server" role to your server), you can choose which features your web server will and will not support. Basic HTTP authentication is exactly one of these (and IIRC it's *not* enabled by default), so first of all you should check if it's actually installed on the server, otherwise you won't even have the option to enable it in IIS itself. You can check this from the Roles and/or Role Services screens in Server Manager.

Comment: exactly the issue. it appears that in a very basic installation of IIS7 it does not by default install the "Basic Authentication" option which is what i need to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to disable integrated authentication:

http://codesnip.net/iis7-integrated-windows-authentication-win-2008

Also here is some more detailed information on how internet explorer reacts:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063